# AdBlock Plus keeps getting enabled again on weather.com

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, adblock

I've been using AdBlock Plus in Chrome for a while. Recently, [www.weather.com](http://www.weather.com) changed so that it forces me to disable my ad blocker in order to use their site.

However, for some reason, no matter how many times I disable it, somehow it keeps getting re-enabled, and I need to switch it off again. It seems to be happening on a daily basis.

Why does this keep happening, and how do I make it permanently disabled for this website?

Chrome version: `84.0.4147.89`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like your extension data got somehow corrupted by the browser, causing your settings to reset each time you restart your browser.

Unfortunately, there's not much the extension can do about such data corruption and even browser makers are having a hard time getting to the bottom of those. However, you could try to [uninstall and reinstall](https://help.eyeo.com/en/adblockplus/data-corruption) the extension to see whether it fixes your problem.

If that doesn't help, the next best option would be to create a new browser profile or to reinstall Chrome.